# SageMaker : Sckit-learn RandomForest : REST API Value ERROR

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, lambda, amazon-sagemaker

My Lambda Code is Below.

```
import os
import io
import boto3
import json
import csv

# grab environment variables
ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = data['data']
    print(payload)
    
    wrapper = csv.reader(payload.strip().split('\n'))
    for record in wrapper:
        print(record)
   
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                       ContentType='text/csv',
                                       Body=wrapper)
    print(response)
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
    
    return result
```

My input value is

```
{
  "data": "231, -43"
}
```

Error message is

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Body, value: <_csv.reader object at 0x7f638af1a6d8>, type: <class '_csv.reader'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      24,
      "lambda_handler",
      "Body=wrapper)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      357,
      "_api_call",
      "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      649,
      "_make_api_call",
      "api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      697,
      "_convert_to_request_dict",
      "api_params, operation_model)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py",
      293,
      "serialize_to_request",
      "raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())"
    ]
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 0e33f157-ae77-4524-96f2-78a2fe82bf5b Version: $LATEST
Received event: {
  "data": "231, -43"
}
231, -43
['231', ' -43']
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: <_csv.reader object at 0x7f638af1a6d8>, type: <class '_csv.reader'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object: ParamValidationError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_handler
    Body=wrapper)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 649, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 697, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py", line 293, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: <_csv.reader object at 0x7f638af1a6d8>, type: <class '_csv.reader'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object

END RequestId: 0e33f157-ae77-4524-96f2-78a2fe82bf5b
REPORT RequestId: 0e33f157-ae77-4524-96f2-78a2fe82bf5b  Duration: 19.80 ms  Billed Duration: 20 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 68 MB  Init Duration: 261.73 ms

Request ID
0e33f157-ae77-4524-96f2-78a2fe82bf5b
```

I don't know the reason about the error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you input the data type JSON? You has defined content type to csv in this code

```
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME, ContentType='text/csv', Body=wrapper) print(response)
```